Block Diagram Reduction in Control Systems


My professor provided a code that shows the different ways to reduce a multiple block diagram.
numg1 = [-1];
deng1 = [2];
numg2 = [0 2];
deng2 = [1 2];
numg3 = -0.125*[1 0.435];
deng3 = conv([1 1.23], [1 0.226 0.0169]);

numh1 = [-1 0];
denh1 = [0 1];

G1 = tf(numg1, deng1);
G2 = tf(numg2, deng2);
G3 = tf(numg3, deng3);

H1=tf (numh1,denh1);

G4=series(G2,G3);  %cascade
G5=feedback(G4,H1); %feedback
Ge=series(G1,G5); %cascade

' T(s) via Series, Parallel, & Feedback Commands'      
T=feedback(Ge,1)   %unity feedback

'Solution via Algebraic Operations'

clear 
numg1=[-1];
deng1=[2]; 
numg2=[0 2]; 
deng2=[1 2]; 
numg3=-0.125*[1 0.435]; 
deng3=conv([1 1.23],[1 0.226 0.0169]);

numh1=[-1 0]; 
denh1=[0 1]; 
G1=tf (numg1,deng1); % Create LTI transfer function, G1(s).
G2=tf (numg2,deng2); % Create LTI transfer function, G2(s).
G3=tf (numg3,deng3); % Create LTI transfer function, G3(s).
H1=tf (numh1,denh1); % Create LTI transfer function, H1(s).
G4=G3*G2;
G5=G4/(1+G4*H1); 
G5=minreal(G5); 
Ge=G5*G1; 

' T(s) via Algebraic Operations' 
T=Ge/(1+Ge); 
T=minreal(T) 


'Solution via Append & Connect Commands'

numg1=[2]; 
deng1=[1 0]; 
G1=tf(numg1,deng1)

 
numg2=[-2 0]; 
deng2=[1 2]; 
G2=tf(numg2,deng2)

numg3=-0.125*[1 0.435];
deng3=conv([1 1.23],[1 0.226 0.0169]);
G3=tf(numg3,deng3)
System=append(G1,G2,G3);
input=1; 

output=3; 
Q=[1 -3 0 
2 1 -3 
3 2 0]; 
T=connect(System,Q,input,output);

' T(s) via Append & Connect Commands'

T=tf(T); 
T=minreal(T) 

My question is the part where the numg1,2 and deng1,2 of 'Solution via Append & Connect Commands' changed compared to the previous methods. Why?

I guess your instructor made an error as the third system is not equivalent to the first two.
